# IllegalFormatConversionException when installing a certificate with keytool and Java 15

Tags: java, windows, certificate, keytool, java-15

I'am having a weird problem installing a certificate in the Java `cacerts`. My JDK is a `15.0.2` version, running in a Windows machine.

The given certificate is correct and I was able to install it in a Docker container based in this image: `azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:15`.

So I try to install the certificate in my Windows machine by executing this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file mycert.crt -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

But then it fails with this error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

I've read on other posts that the solution was using this flag: `-J-Duser.language=en`. But mi `keytool` then says that it does not recognize that flag.

Some ideas, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `keytool` is running the jdk15 version, i.e. do you have any other Java version(s) present on the Windows machine? Do `where keytool`. Is this from the Oracle package, or OpenJDK, and which and from whom? (Oracle builds since j9 no longer use a jdk-$version/jre subdirectory, so for that filename they would give you FileNotFoundException.) (Oracle 15.0.2 on my Windows accepts `-J-Duser.language=` although since I am a US person my system _already_ has language en.)